# write C program to compute the numeric root

Tags: c

The numeric root of x is computed as follows:
a) Compute the sum, y, of all of x’s (decimal) digits;
b) If y is greater than 10, then set x to y and go to step a). Otherwise, y is x’s numerical root.
Thus, the numeric root of 10, 202 and 875 are 1, 4 and 2, respectively.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    int x, y, index, found;

    found = 0;
    scanf("%d", &x);

    if (x < 0)
    {
        printf("The input number must be nonnegative.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        y = 0;
        index = x % 10;

        while (found != 1)
        {
            while (x > 10)
            {
                y = y + index;
                x = (x - index) / 10;
                index = x % 10;
            }

            y = y + index;

            if (y < 10)
            {
                printf("%d\n", y);
                found = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                x = y;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My output are always numbers like "-2147483623" etc.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: use your debugger

Comment: Note that `x = (x-index)/10;` can be safely replaced by `x = x / 10;`

Comment: Using the debugger is a good idea. The other option is to use `printf` to display the values of `x`, `y`, and `index` at various points in the program.

Comment: My running of the code is 10 -> 0, 202 -> 4, and 875 -> -2147483616. Learning how to use a debugger, as mentioned above, is part of learning to program.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution can be greatly simplified with the use of a simple function. 
See the following solution using the Ada language:

```
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_Io;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   Inpt_Value : Natural;
   Root       : Natural := 0;
   function Find_Root(X : Natural) return Natural is
      Value : Natural := X;
      Root  : Natural := 0;
   begin
      while Value > 0 loop
         Root  := Root + (Value mod 10);
         Value := Value / 10;
      end loop;
      return Root;
   end Find_Root;

begin
   Put("Enter a non-negative integer: ");
   Get(Item => Inpt_Value);
   Root := Find_Root(Inpt_Value);
   while Root > 10 loop
      Root := Find_Root(Root);
   end loop;
   Put_Line(Root'Image);
end Main;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is here :

```
if(y < 10){
    printf("%d\n",y);
    found = 1;
  }
  else{
    x = y;
  }
```

in your else statement you assign the value of `x` to `y`, but you don't change the value of `y`.

Maybe you should do something like this :

```
if(y < 10){
    printf("%d\n",y);
    found = 1;
  }
  else{
    x = y;
    y = 0;
    index = x % 10;
  }
```

In your entire program you don't seem to decrease or reset the value of `y`, that's why once the else block entered, there is no way to enter the if block, because `y` will increase and always be greater than 10 until an overflow happens, that's why `y` is negative at the end.

PS: Always use a debugger or `printf` statements it will help you detect such problems.

Comment: ie - add y = 0 after x = y

Comment: Need also to add `index = x % 10` in that section. So both `y` and `index` need to be properly re-initialized. I think the commenters generally know this, but trying to avoid giving away the answer to an OP that should learn some debugging. But alas...

Comment: I got that ! Thanks a lot !